# How to get the rowid of a selected element from a listview

Tags: sqlite, listview, jquery-mobile

I have a table in my database. Each time addvaluetodb() is called, it creates a new row in the table and this signifies a single record. Each record is then displayed in a listview in the JQM style. Now I want to update the record when I click on a list item, so I was wondering, how do you get the rowid of the item that you click in the listview? So far I have:

```
function updateRecord(){
    if (!window.openDatabase) {
        alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
        return;
    }

    db.transaction(function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql('UPDATE Income SET column1 = "updated" WHERE Id = ?  \
                               ',
                               nullHandler, errorHandler);
    });

    return;
}
```

That is a test function which updates a single column of the item that is clicked, but I'm not sure how to get the ID of that list item. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Below is the code that I used to create the listview.

```
transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Income ORDER BY date DESC', [],
                  function(transaction, result) {
                  if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
                  for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                  var row = result.rows.item(i);
                  $('#records').append('<li><a href ="javascript: updateRecord()">' + 'item1: ' + row['column1'] + '<br>' + 'item2: ' + row['column2'] + '<br>' + 'item3: ' + row['column3'] + '<br>' + 'item4: ' + row['column4'] + '</a></li>');

                  $( "#records" ).listview().listview("refresh");
                  }
                  }
                  },errorHandler);
},errorHandler,nullHandler);
```

EDIT:  I should add, by the rowid of the list item I mean the id relating to the database of that row.  So if it was the first row it would be 1 etc.  I wanted to know how to get this value when I click on any list item (which represents a row in the table).

EDIT:  Here is the update code

```
db.transaction(function(transaction) {
                          transaction.executeSql('UPDATE Income SET column1 = "updated" WHERE UserId = '+rowid+'\
                                                 ',
                                                 nullHandler);
                          });
```

It works fine, listview just wont render to the new text

Comment: Do you use the rowid as the id of the listitem? do you put it in a data attribute? Show us the code that creates the listview...

Comment: @ezanker I have added the code used to create the listview.  The list elements themselves don't have ids, are you implying that I should set the rowid to the id of the list element?  If so, the way I'm creating the list elements, how would I have a unique id for each?  Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In creating the listview you only need to call `.listview("refresh");` once after the for loop. If the UL is already in the HTML markup, you don't need the `.listview()`, just the refresh.  I would assign the rowid to a data attribute on the listitem and instead of calling javascript within the anchor assign it a class and handle the event. Assuming rowid is in column0:

```
function(transaction, result) {
    if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
        var allItems = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
            var row = result.rows.item(i);          
            allItems +='<li data-rowid="' + row['column0'] + '"><a href ="#" class="updateRecordButton">' + 'item1: ' + row['column1'] + '<br>' + 'item2: ' + row['column2'] + '<br>' + 'item3: ' + row['column3'] + '<br>' + 'item4: ' + row['column4'] + '</a></li>';
        }
        $( "#records" ).append(allItems).listview().listview("refresh");
    }
},errorHandler);
```

Now you add a click handler (using event delegation) for the class, updateRecordButton, and get the rowid from the parent LI data attribute:

```
$(document).on("click", ".updateRecordButton", function(){
    var rowid = $(this).parents("li").data("rowid");
    //call your update code
    updateRecord(rowid);
});
```

Comment: Thanks this works!  I just had a a question.  Since, I'm using a jQuery Mobile style listview, when I click to update a column, the writing doesn't change automatically, it changes when I refresh the page.  I've tried putting in trigger('change') in various places but no luck.  Your answer answered my question perfectly though, thanks

Comment: Added the update code, it's the same as before but I added in the rowid part.  Just having trouble refreshing the listview to show the updated text

Comment: I see the code that updates the database, but where and how are you writing new text to the listitems?

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I just called the listdbvalues() function after updating the database and it worked :) Thanks for the help